# How can i find why RestSharp PUT throw Exception?

Tags: c#, uwp, restsharp

I've sent a `PUT` request and got `NullReferenceException` in `RestSharp.Portable`:

```
using (var client = new RestClient(new Uri(BaseUri)))
{
    var oAuth1Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(
      OAuthConsumerKey,
      OAuthConsumerSecret,
      oAuthToken", 
      oAuthSecret"
    );

    client.Authenticator = oAuth1Authenticator;

    var request = new RestRequest(lastPartUri, httpMethod);

    request.AddJsonBody(body);

    IRestResponse response = await client.Execute(request);

    return response.Content;
}
```

Line `IRestResponse response = await client.Execute(request);` thrown the exception.

OAuth params are definitely not `null`, neither are `BaseUri` and `lastPartUri`. `body` is  a `Dictionary<string, string>` and is not null too.

`POST` and `GET` requests with the same parameters work just fine.

Looks like the problem is in `RestSharp` library. How can I find it?

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at RestSharp.Portable.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.<>c.<AddOAuthData>b__84_3(Parameter p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at RestSharp.Portable.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.AddOAuthData(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, OAuthWorkflow workflow)
   at RestSharp.Portable.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.PreAuthenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
   at RestSharp.Portable.RestClientBase.<ExecuteRequest>d__67.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient.RestClient.<Execute>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Store.Helpers.MyBookApiConnector.<SendRequest>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Store.Services.DataService.<UpdateReview>d__80.MoveNext()
```

[image: Before exception]
[image: After exception]

Comment: From the stacktrace, it looks like the null reference exception is occurring in the `OAuthAutheticator`. Do any of the values supplied to the Authenticator have the value `null`?

Comment: I dont know much C#, but isn't OP missing a semicolon after the `var 01Auth...` block of code?

Comment: @LarsKristensen values not null.


I'm updated question.

Comment: @DrSatan1 yes, it is after edit for SO.

Comment: @Enigmativity reopen question!

Comment: @MakeMakeluv - Why do you think it is not a duplicate?

Comment: I'm not ask about what is it NullReferenceException. I'm ask how find why ecxeption throw only on PUT method only on RestSharp.

Comment: Hey, @Enigmativity, this question looks to be valid, not a duplicate. It may be [a bug in `RestSharp`](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/issues/84), but definitely it's not a "what is a NRE?" question. Can you please consider a possibility to reopen it? Even if it will not get an answer, it may help others to track that defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed a bug in the library. The developer is already fixed.